# How to listed all the tables of a User in a database? n

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi so i have the following plan : 
i want to Write a script, which calls another script. A parameter V_USERNAME should be passed from the 1st script to the 2nd script.( Using the keyword DEFINE)

My code look like :

```
@@C:\Users\pe.k\Documents\script2.sql &p_v_username

set serveroutput on

define p_v_username =  "user";
```

In the 2nd script all tables of the user should be output. (Using the key word EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and a cursor).

The output control is to be done via a parameter in the script or when calling the script.

Example call:
SQL> @start_script1 MML

```
declare 
    &p_v_username  varchar2(100); 
    v_result    varchar2(100);
    cursor cp_username (&p_v_username varchar2) 
    is
        select owner, table_name           
        from all_tables
        where owner = &p_v_username  
        order by owner, table_name;       
begin 
     dbms_output.put_line('Alle Tabellen der User'); --l_username);
     open cp_username(&p_v_username);
     --loop
         --fetch cp_username into v_result;
        -- dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
    --end loop;
     close cp_username;
end;
/
```

And i have the errors and i am lost. I dont know how to do it

Comment: How about changing that "plan"? I mean, what you do is to display list of tables someone has access to in one of the most complicated ways one could think of (one script calling another passing this and that, looping through a cursor ...). What's wrong with SELECT statement you currently have in the cursor? You'll get the same (or better) result with much less effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your second procedure should be something like this:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Alle Tabellen der User'); --l_username);
    FOR TABS IN (
        SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
        FROM ALL_TABLES
        WHERE OWNER = '&P_V_USERNAME'
        ORDER BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
    ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABS.TABLE_NAME);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

In order to print the output generated by the DBMS_OUTPUT package from PL/SQL, make sure to `set serveroutput on`

Comment: Thanks but i want to use a cursor for this part of select that's why and i want to listed all the tables with the name of the owner.

Comment: For Loop query cursor, nothing else!!